# TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I am trying to send a post request from site to server which includes user input data. I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'vehicle' of undefined as a response here.

HTML and script data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Car Finder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <center><h1>Craigslist Vehicle Finder</h1></center>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" name="vehicle" value="" id="vehicle">
            <label for="vehicle">Vehicle</label>
        </form>
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" name="miles" value="" id="miles">
            <label for="miles">Miles</label>
        </form>
        <label class="container">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
            <label for="checkbox">Manual</label>
        </label>   
        <select id="select" class="City">
            <option value="null">Select Location</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <form class="submit Search">
            <input type="submit" value="Search Craigslist"><br/>
        </form>
        <script>
            var select = document.getElementById("select"),
                    arr = ["atlanta","austin","boston","chicago","dallas","denver","detroit","houston","lasvegas","losangeles","miami","minneapolis","newyork","newhaven","orangecounty","philadelphia","phoenix","portland","raleigh","sacramento","san diego","seattle","sfbay","washingtondc"];

                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement ("OPTION"),
                        txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
                    option.appendChild(txt);
                    select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
                }
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.post('http://localhost:3000', { vehicle: 'input#vehicle', miles: 'input#miles', location: 'select' }, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server side method to receive the POST data:

```
app.post('/', (req, res, err) => {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log(req.body.vehicle)
        console.log(req.body.miles)
        console.log(req.body.location)
    }
})
```

using express server btw

Comment: Try to log the `req.body` and see what it has?  Also the following is invalid.  `$.post('http://localhost:3000', { vehicle: 'input#vehicle', miles: 'input#miles', location: 'select' }, function (err, result) {`  You are literally sending those strings as the values of those keys, not looking the elements up on the page.

Comment: Try: `$.post('http://localhost:3000', { vehicle: $('input#vehicle').val(), miles: $('input#miles').val(), location: $('select').val() }, function (err, result) {`

Comment: `return data;`... And where the `data` come from? --- And return it where?

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' as a response when I log the body using both suggestions

Comment: What if you just log the `req`?

Comment: On the line number you have for the error... What is the code?

Comment: Okay... Try: `$.post('http://localhost:3000', { vehicle: $('input#vehicle').val(), miles: $('input#miles').val(), location: $('select').val() }).then(function (err, result) {` and console.log `err` and `result`.

Comment: A ton of socket data is coming through when I log the req. In chrome I am still getting 'POST http://localhost:3000/ 0 ()' in console though and the data doesnt have the information that I need. Edit: it magically disappeared

Comment: If I use charlesProxy its clear that none of the data is even getting into the request.  vehicle 
miles 
location null

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm module called `body-parser` that extracts form data and sends that data to the `req.body` object. Using this module, you will be able to access form elements by name, in this case `req.body.vehicle` in your route handlers which should solve the issue. May be worth checking out the documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

EDIT: So I gave this a try using `body-parser` and got req.body printing out form contents in route handler. Hope this helps :)

app.js (Express code)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.post('/findvehicle', urlencodedParser, function (req, res, err) {

        console.log(req.body.vehicle);
        console.log(req.body.miles);
        console.log(req.body.location);
        res.redirect('index.html');
});

app.listen("2000");
```

index.html

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/findvehicle" >
        <input type="text" name="vehicle" value="" id="vehicle">
        <label for="vehicle">Vehicle</label>
        <input type="text" name="miles" value="" id="miles">
        <label for="miles">Miles</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="location" id="option1" value="Atlanta" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Atlanta
        <input type="checkbox" name="location" id="option2" value="Austin" autocomplete="off"> Austin
        <label for="miles">Location</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Search Craigslist"><br/>
</form>
```